# How do you write the end of a file opened with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING?

Tags: winapi, vb6, file-io, buffer

I am using VB6 and the Win32 API to write data to a file, this functionality is for the export of data, therefore write performance to the disk is the key factor in my considerations. As such I am using the `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` and `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` options when opening the file with a call to `CreateFile`.

`FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` requires that I use my own buffer and write data to the file in multiples of the disk's sector size, this is no problem generally, apart from the last part of data, which if it is not an exact multiple of the sector size will include character zero's padding out the file, how do I set the file size once the last block is written to not include these character zero's?

I can use `SetEndOfFile` however this requires me to close the file and re-open it without using `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`. I have seen someone talk about `NtSetInformationFile` however I cannot find how to use and declare this in VB6. `SetFileInformationByHandle` can do exactly what I want however it is only available in Windows Vista, my application needs to be compatible with previous versions of Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but are YOU sure that setting `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` and `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` give you maximum performance?

They'll certainly result in your data hitting the disk as soon as possible, but that sort of thing doesn't actually help performance - it just helps reliability for things like journal files that you want to be as complete as possible in the event of a crash.

For a data export routine like you describe, allowing the operating system to buffer your data will probably result in BETTER performance, since the writes will be scheduled in line with other disk activity, rather than forcing the disk to jump back to your file every write.

Why don't you benchmark your code without those options?  Leave in the zero-byte padding logic to make it a fair test.

If it turns out that skipping those options is faster, then you can remove the 0-padding logic, and your file size issue fixes itself.

Comment: That is a very interesting point, I had intended to benchmark the various different ways of writing to the file, but thanks for your suggestion nonetheless. What led me to try this method was a blog post (http://www.winasm.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=794) on winasm.net.

Comment: While you might be right in this particular case, that's not an answer to the question.

Comment: Marvin, well, yes, it didn't answer the question (gabr did that).  But it DID solve the underlying problem, and speed up the process.  :)

Answer (score 4):

I believe SetEndOfFile is the only way.

And I agree with Mike G. that you should bench your code with and without FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING. Windows file buffering on modern OS's is pretty darn effective.

Comment: The rest of the answers don't answer the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

For a one-gigabyte file, Windows buffering will indeed probably be faster, especially if doing many small I/Os.  If you're dealing with files which are much larger than available RAM, and doing large-block I/O, the flags you were setting WILL produce must better throughput (up to three times faster for heavily threaded and/or random large-block I/O).